# Combining test string from CSV with

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file containing user aliases in first.last name format.

I am attempting to pull these aliases one-by-one and combine them with our domain, to create their email address.

Here is my code:

```
$CSV = Import-CSV "\\this\is\thepath\to\the\csv.csv" 
$domain = "@domain.co.uk"
$CSV.Alias | ForEach-Object (
    Write-Host ($CSV.Alias + $domain)
)
```

the output I need, is:

```
John.Doe@domain.co.uk Jane.Doe@domain.co.uk John.Smith@domain.co.uk
```

However, this is what's being output:

```
John.Doe Jane.Doe John.Smith  @domain.co.uk
```

Comment: `$CSV.Alias + $domain` -> `$_ + $domain`

Comment: Also, note that `ForEach-Object` should have curly brackets `{ }` instead of round ones `( )`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$CSV = Import-CSV '\\this\is\thepath\to\the\csv.csv' 
$domain = '@domain.co.uk'
$CSV.Alias | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_ + $domain
}
```

If I apply it to this input file:

```
Alias
John.Doe
Jane.Doe
John.Smith
```

I get this output.

```
John.Doe@domain.co.uk
Jane.Doe@domain.co.uk
John.Smith@domain.co.uk
```

All I did was to correct two bugs in your attempt, the two bugs that were pointed out in the comments to the question.   Plus I made two cosmetic changes.

One cosmetic change was to use single quotes in a couple of places where you used double quotes.  If you don't need the transformations that double quotes invoke,  don't use them.  Use single quotes instead.  This is just defensive coding.

Another cosmetic change was to remove the parentheses surrounding the argument to Write-Host.  It works without those parentheses. One might argue that the parentheses should be in there anyway, to make it easier to read.  OK.